# Should this question about dos2unix really be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

I came across this question, and I'm completely puzzled by it being closed: *[How can I run dos2unix on an entire directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929461/how-can-i-run-dos2unix-on-an-entire-directory)*

Perhaps this question could have been asked on a Linux-related Stack Exchange site, but I do feel that you're a lot more likely to need [dos2unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) when developing software than when doing anything else. And if you're not doing software development, you're probably doing something in a closely related field. So, it does not appear to me that this question should be closed, but I'm also not quite sure why people would think that it should.

Am I missing or misunderstanding something or should this question never have been closed?

Comment: It's not a unique problem to software development. It's a rather mundane and general problem that *NIX users would face. It's really just "how do I use command line to do X" in the end. You can also replace `dos2unix` with `wc` or many other tools.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me to have anything to do with software development. It is not even asked in the context of software development.

Comment: @VLAZ What I'm reading is the question "how do I change all line endings (using tool x)". The answer is more generically applicable and mundane, but I'd say that the question is pretty much unique to programming. Though perhaps I'm focusing a bit much on the intent rather than the written words.

Comment: Line endings are unique to programming?

Comment: @Jasper it's not. There are some files that can cause problems or at least annoyance if they have the wrong line endings and that's just for the user of a *NIX system. They don't even have to be a programmer. Doing a few things with the console doesn't mean they are programming.

Comment: @VLAZ True. However, it's not often that such users are changing line endings in a lot of files at once. Perhaps it's not 100% unique, but I'd say it's at least 85% unique. Perhaps that's not enough, though

Comment: There's no programming language specified, so how would you answer this, in a "programming" sense?

Comment: @Jasper I'm not sure your expectation of a Linux user is correct. If I transfer a bunch of files from Windows to Linux, I might want to fix all their line endings. And the files could just be recipes for cakes. Or config files. Or whatever. They don't need to be about programming. In fact, I can barely remember any times I've had to run `dos2unix` or `unix2dos`  for programming files. It has happened but most times I've done it because an application on either side of the OSes just doesn't quite like one of the line endings.

Comment: Besides, you're overlooking the fact that "run a command against a bunch of files" is intrinsically a *NIX thing. And what the command is usually has little relevance. There are a whole bunch of approaches that don't rely on the command at all. For some it's just `command *` but that's hardly a programming topic, either. You're arguing that `dos2unux` is in some way more "programming" than `wc` or something even though the approaches would be largely be the same for either. Or is `wc` also a programming tool?

Comment: @Cerbrus There is no programming language specified in - for example - most git question. By itself, that does not make those questions off topic

Comment: @Jasper Sure, but Git is a source control too mostly used in development.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm not overlooking it. In fact, I specifically addressed it. However, I think that the question comes from a need to perform a task, not from an understanding of the tool in the context of its operating system, thus I'd say the task to be performed should be evaluated on whether it's on topic, not the larger understanding of the tool, which the user asking the question might not have. But perhaps that's not a belief shared by you or others on this site.

Comment: @Jasper if developers are more likely to use a generic feature like copy and paste, then should questions about copying and pasting be posted on SO instead of SU? Or is the nature of the task of copying and pasting generic enough to be a aimed as SU regardless of who uses it more?

Comment: @VLAZ Going with your example, imagine that a symbol commonly used in programming commonly gets corrupted when copy-pasting on a specific OS. Then, I'd say that yes, questions about that problem would fit on SO. That's not to say it would not fit on SU. I'd say it would exist in that space where it would fit on either, which isn't that big a space, but it wouldn't be the only question in that space.

Comment: No, that question would still be off-topic. If  `=` gets magically "corrupted" by the process of an end-user copy-pasting in WhateverOs, it's not a programming issue. If it got corrupted by using a programming API for copying and pasting? Then, sure, it could be on-topic.

Comment: To my mind, the real problem is that this question was closed.  It is that too many other questions like this don't get closed.

Comment: @yivi Opinion noted. Would love to note arguments as well, though. (Also, I think `"` being converted to `“` is a better example than `=` getting "corrupted", as it's something that many average users wouldn't care about, but would matter a lot when programming -- but is not 100% related to programming like the real question as well)

Comment: @Jasper Yes, if there is a *specific* problem which is *about programming*, then it can be posted on SO. I don't think why you need to come up with a fictional example for that - it's commonly accepted. I also don't know how your *specific* problem which is *about programming* relates to the *generic* task which is *not about programming* I presented. The question was should such a problem posted on SO instead of SU based on usage statistics. It was definitely not about something very different and incompatible with it.

Comment: @VLAZ You came up with the idea of a copy-pasting analogy. All I did was add (fictional) details to it to the point where - for me - the answer would indeed be the same. Without those details, it's your analogy that doesn't hit the relevant points in my opinion. So yeah, I felt the need to come up with to show that your analogy, does apply in my opinion if you do not leave out the relevant details.

Comment: Also, I believe you are reading things into the question that weren't there. It was not about SU, it was not about posting it in one place *instead of* somewhere else and it was not about where a question should be posted. It was about whether or not questions like this should be disallowed on SO, which does not mean it could/should/would be posted elsewhere and does not say anything about the best place to post it.

Comment: "*All I did was add (fictional) details to it to the point*" and thus made it *about* a programming problem. And not about usage statistics. That was your main argument before - the *who* uses it more rather than what it is about.  If you want to not argue that any more, then you have yet to prove that `dos2unix` is specific to programming and not a generic tool.

Comment: @VLAZ Exactly, I made it about programming, in a way that I think is the same way the actual question is about programming. It's true that I didn't address the usage statistics *at that specific point in time*. That's not because I believe it disproved and am switching arguments (I don't and I'm not). It's because I believe it to be an unresolved point. And it's true I haven't provided any hard numbers about such things. It's also true nobody has provided the counter-numbers either. I don't know where the burden of proof should be, but I'd say closing a question definitely carries some of it

Comment: Earlier this week someone washed a config file through Windows and broke the line endings. Rather than dos2unix the file I fixed up the config parser to remove a source of future problems.

Comment: Slightly related (2009): *[What is the most rampant duplicate on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9686/what-is-the-most-rampant-duplicate-on-stack-exchange-sites/168291#168291)*

Comment: Wasn't there a meta question recently (within a few weeks or months) about the same 'dos2unix'  Stack Overflow question? Or a very close equivalent? It *could* have been (automatically) deleted.

Comment: @Jasper " I don't know where the burden of proof should be, but I'd say closing a question definitely carries some of it" - I would agree for a site that does not have to process thousands of questions. Stack Overflow does not apply, you need to reason with different standards and motives.

Comment: @Gimby I do understand where you are coming from, but I also think that's the kind of mentality that makes people consider SO unwelcoming and unkind and that's a thing SO has been trying to fight the past few years. (Also, note that I didn't say that the proof would need to be provided up front for every closure, the context was that we were discussing the burden of proof on a meta question.)

Answer (score 9):

There are probably two aspects to this, so I will discuss both:

### [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)

The tool converts the line endings from Windows style CRLF to Unix style LF.

The `dos2unix` tool itself is not a tool closely related to programming. Sure programmers would need it some times but maybe so would sysadmins, IT personnel, data scientists, or just regular users who decided to move their files from Windows to Linux.

At the end of the day, there is still some software that is a bit fussy about line endings and you might want to convert them appropriately. It does not matter what your main occupation is - such software exist everywhere. For example, I have seen some editors which show empty lines between each line of text due to the CRLF line ending. Trying to view a recipe for pancakes would be annoying.

I do not believe `dos2unix` to have special meaning for programming. It is a generic tool that is neither tailored towards programmers nor is uniquely required by them. At best, we can say that power users would find purpose for it.

### How to run a command against a directory of files

The question is for `dos2unix` but having to apply that to a directory  is similarly not a unique problem to software development. It is intrinsically a problem that *NIX users would face. The same problem can be formulated with other tools like [`wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc), or [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file), or [`touch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) or many others. The solution would be largely the same for all of them - there are generic approaches to run a command on multiple files at once. The type of command often does not make a difference

Comment: "Sure programmers would need it some times but maybe so would sysadmins, IT personnel, data scientists, or just regular users who decided to move their files from Windows to Linux." I disagree with this. Modern text editors on all OSs handle `\r\n` or `\n` as line endings just fine. The _only_ people who really need it these days, it seems to me, are people using `git` who don't want to see everything red in `git status` just because they copied over a folder and line endings differ. So, I view this as essentially a pure software problem, hence why Stack Overflow is fine for it.

Comment: @GabrielStaples you imply that the real question here is "How do I make sure that I don't see everything red in Git" (X) which is [a *different* question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to "how do I run dos2unix over a directory" (Y). The X would be on-topic. And might have solutions other than Y.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is fine to be closed.

The general usecase matches *any* text file transferred between Windows and Unix. It is not unique to source code, let alone programming.
No specific programming context is added by the question. It does not raise a specific programming problem or ask for a software algorithm.

In short, it is just not about programming. [Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) – and this question does not.

Comment: In the question, I stated that I believe it to be mostly relevant in programming related situations. Do you think that belief is inaccurate, or that it does not matter as long as it is applicable to any other situations? (which I wouldn't say are all text files transferred from Windows, but that's not all that relevant)

Comment: @Jasper "Do you think that belief is inaccurate" Yes. Frankly I have no idea how you even come to believe that.

Comment: @Jasper "or that it does not matter as long as it is applicable to any other situations" No. I think the phrasing "primarily for programming" is clear on that. It's not sufficient that there is just any other applicable situation, it has to be a prominent one.

Comment: I don't have a particularly strong foundation. But to explain how I got to that: mostly personal experience; with most programs handling both fine, many windows programs having at least the option to generate unix line endings and most average users not using a lot of text files, I'd say it's mostly down to config files and source files. For config files, it's mostly about what the configured program supports. For source files, it's also about consistency within a project, thus that's where I expect mass changing. Maybe I'm entirely wrong, but that's how I got to that belief

Comment: @Jasper As someone making their money with a mix of administration and programming, while using \*Nix but having family using Windows: I would say mostly the use-case of `dos2unix` is just not relevant at all today, sometimes relevant when muggles use computers too much, rarely relevant for configuration/administration because of inconsistent tooling and non-technical people, and almost never relevant for programming because *that* tooling does it right automatically.

Comment: Agreed on it not being that relevant in general. I have, however, come across plenty of repositories where developers checked in some code in different line endings (unintentionally) and my tools generally going with whatever the file happens to be in. That said, you usually don't have to change it, but I expected not to be the only one annoyed by it, and it thus being a relatively common use-case. But yeah, that's purely anecdotal and speculation and may be wrong.

Comment: @Jasper "how to get files from Git repo and normalize line endings" would be on-topic, and "use dos2unix" may be even suggested as an alternative answer.

Answer (score -2):

Let me present an alternative viewpoint to the other answers here:

The [going argument](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416771/4561887) is:

> Sure programmers would need it some times but maybe so would sysadmins, IT personnel, data scientists, or just regular users who decided to move their files from Windows to Linux.

I disagree with this. Modern text editors on all OSs handle `\r\n` or `\n` as line endings just fine. The *only* people who really need it these days, it seems to me, are people using `git` who don't want to see everything red in `git status` just because they copied over a folder and line endings differ. So, I view this as primarily a software development problem, hence why Stack Overflow is fine for it.